# Can you call upon a var, not its value, out of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

Working on a JS BlackJack app and running into a few problems. I have mar deck (cards array) and my face cards have defined values. I random select cards for each player and it adds and displays the card value, but i want to be able to display a card img for each. So, i can not differentiate b/w the face cards.

```
var j = 10;
var q = 10;
var k = 10;
var cards = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, j, j, j, j, q, q, q, q, k, k, k, k, a, a, a, a];
function processIt() {
    //player's hand
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    var card1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length));
    var card2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length));
    totalPlayer = cards[card1] + cards[card2];
    cardDisplayP = cards[card1] + " " + cards[card2];
    player.innerHTML = cardDisplayP + "<br />" + "Total: " + totalPlayer;
```

so, is there any way I can call upon the var and not its value out of an array?
i.e. I want:

```
show var.cards[46] = k;
cards[46] = 10;
```

Comment: Maybe each card shuld have both a value and a suite, instead of just a value? Not sure what your question means, though; are you asking if you can have an object in an array? (Yes.)

Comment: sorry I'm new to JS, would i do that by using a constructor?

Comment: You could use a simple object for each card `{value: 2, suit: 'c'}` (or however you want to encode the suits).

Comment: You could, or a simple object, e.g., { value: 8, suit: "clubs" }, probably other options as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on position in the array, you should create constructors or objects to contain data about your cards. Here's an example with constructors:

```
var Suit = {
    Hearts: 0,
    Diamonds: 1,
    Clubs: 2,
    Spades: 3,
    '0': '♥',
    '1': '♦',
    '2': '♣',
    '3': '♠'
};

if(Object.freeze) {
    Object.freeze(Suit);
}

function Card(suit, value) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

Card.faceValue = function(value) {
    if(value > 1 && value < 11) {
        return value.toString();
    } else if(value === 1) {
        return 'A';
    } else {
        return ['J', 'Q', 'K'][value % 10 - 1];
    }
};

Card.prototype.toString = function() {
    return Card.faceValue(this.value) + Suit[this.suit];
};

function Deck() {
    for(var value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
        for(var suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
            this.push(new Card(suit, value));
        }
    }
}

Deck.prototype = [];
Deck.prototype.constructor = Deck;
Deck.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    this.sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
    });
};

var d = new Deck();
d.shuffle();
document.write(d);
```

And `Deck` inherits from array, so you can just use `.pop()` to get the top card.

[Here's the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/CG3gM/)